# Auto format inline whitespace with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble finding the auto format command to remove the extra white-space in this example:

```
    public bool IsTooMuchPadding
    {
        get            {                return True;            };
    }
```

I have tried the various hotkeys <kbd>ctrl + k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl + f</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl + e</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl + f</kbd> but they have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS won't format invalid code. Are you sure there isn't a compiler warning present along the lines of `Semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid`?

```
public bool IsTooMuchPadding
{
    get            {                return true;            }
}
```

Without the additional semicolon on the `true` line should work.

Edit: A not entirely complete update, but my initial answer was based on another machine which compiles perfectly happily with `return True;` I'm not entirely sure why I can't replicate that on any of my home machines - I'll update as soon as I can replicate.

Further Edit: I can't seem to replicate, puzzled.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are seeing `True` as a valid value.  This does not compile.

Comment: Just replied on your answer, it does compile without issue on my work machine (which is why I didn't bother correcting the True, although thought it was odd), just investigating further at home.

Comment: Where else in the world can you get a group of intelligent people working this hard to find EXACTLY the correct answer to such a simple question. :D  I love SO.

Comment: Haha, a large collection of people who just "can't let it go" =D

Comment: @paqogomez For whatever reason, I now can't seem to replicate the conditions. This is really odd, as I think I remember (I'm now wondering if I was imaging the entire thing) pasting the code to verify that was the problem, and the `True` turned blue. I'll have a further play, maybe I dreamed the whole thing. I'd be interested to know why it works for the OP =o

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl + k</kbd> <kbd>ctrl + d</kbd>

will format the code

Clicking on `EDIT` => `Advanced` => `Format Document` will do the same.

This will not work if you have syntax errors.

In your case the syntax error is in `True` instead of `true` and a semi colon after the get statement:

It should look like this:

```
public bool IsTooMuchPadding
{
  get { return true; }
}
```

Comment: VS formats despite the different cases with True|true; the semicolon was the key.

Comment: @E.Beach, glad you got it working, but dont understand why you gave the guy last to the game the check mark.

Comment: Define last to the game?  It was the first answer in the list that answered the question correctly and didn't refer to `True` as a syntax error.

Comment: @E.Beach FWIW, I dont know what version of VS you are using, but `True` is not syntactically valid in 2013. And I suspect in all other versions as well.

Comment: @paqogomez Oddly, I had quickly tested my original answer on a work machine, which was perfectly happy with `True` (so I didn't think to examine it further), now I'm back at home and `True` does indeed seem invalid. Some examination required =o

Comment: @Chris That is crazy.  I'd like to understand the difference, let me know what you find.

Comment: @paqogomez It is indeed, I've got three versions of VS at home, and they all think it's invalid - my work machine is off so I can't remote in, but I'll take a look first think in the morning. Really odd o.O It might be an oddity with a particular setup of VS 2012, that's what I had at work, and what the OP seems to be using.

Comment: @Chris I'll just stick with it being syntactically invalid then.

Comment: @Chris, FWIW, if you edit your answer, i'll reinstate my +1. :)

Comment: @paqogomez Haha, will do - and I'll update it tomorrow with more info after I see what's going on with my work computer =D

Answer (score 3):

First correct the syntax:

```
public bool IsTooMuchPadding
    {
        get            {                return true;            }
    }
```

Then use ctrl+k ctrl+d

RESULT:

```
public bool IsTooMuchPadding
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Didnt get a chance to say thanks on the syntax issue, I did upvote you however.  I'm not crazy right? `True` is not valid.  OP is saying that `True` is valid, but its not in my compiler.

Comment: you are not crazy, under normal circumstances, true has to be all lowercase.